# Hierarchy chart of 250+ shops and 35,000 employees

Tags: r

are there any tips for make org charts for a 35,000 member organization?

I've attached an org chart for a single shop.

Scenario: We have 250+ shops. Each shop is made up of multiple sections. Each section has a unique section name. Each section is made up of a different amount of managers, technicians, and supervisors. Each shop can be considered a child that reports to a parent. Each parent not only has that particular child shop, but also can have multiple other shops under them as well. That parent can also be a child to a different shop, which is making group_by a challenge. A is a child to parent B, but B is also a child to parent C, who is also a child to parent D, for example.

source doc is an excel doc with 35,000 rows and 50+ columns. Each shop is identified by a shop code and each shop code reports to a parent with it's own shop code.

group_by(parent id, child id might not work because a parent to one shop can be a child to a different parent.

```
Unit ID     Reports To  Unit name   managers in unit    supervisors in unit     technicians in unit

10  11  i   2   0   4
9   11  h   2   1   0
8   9   g   4   3   2
6   7   f   2   3   4
5   7   e   1   2   3
4   5   d   2   1   0
3   4   c   4   3   2
2   4   b   2   3   4
1   2   a   1   2   3
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for BALKAN OrgChartJS, it has the functionalities you are asking for:

[Code demo](https://code.balkan.app/org-chart-js/performance#JS) with chart and 100k nodes (rows)

[Code demo](https://code.balkan.app/org-chart-js/importing#JS) for Import from CSV file and other formats

Also you can read directly from  the Excel(CSV) file with http request and load the chart, without any server side code

Disclaimer: I'm a developer in BALKAN App